# Hibernate how to add restriction for filtering result by Integer id column

Tags: hibernate, restrictions

Want to ask how to add restriction for filtering result by Integer id column

I need something like

`Restriction.like("id", myFilterValue)`   // id is Integer primary key

Comment: This is a very basic questions. Read hibernate docs http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve an object by its primary key in Hibernate, you can use `Session.get()`:

```
Foo foo = session.get(Foo.class, id);
```

Otherwise, if you want to add an equality restriction using Criteria:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id);
List foos = crit.list();
```

I suppose if what you *really* want is to find any rows where the decimal digits of the numeric column contain a certain substring of digits, then you would have to CAST the column to a `VARCHAR` (the syntax of which may vary between databases, and you didn't specify which one you are using) and then you would be able to use something like `WHERE CAST(id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%12%'`. But if you are doing this, you may need to reconsider what you are trying to accomplish at a much higher level, as this would lead me to believe that there may be a problem with the basic design of your system.

Comment: I need get list of objects (for ex. I have rows in table with id 123, 1233, 23123, 12...) and want to find objects that have id like '12'

Comment: I tried Restrictions.sqlRestriction("id like '%" + myFilterValue + '%''), but still not working

Comment: Do you mean where the `id` contains the digits (for example) "`12`" anywhere within the number? In most databases you can't do that with integer columns (`LIKE` works for strings only), and it sounds like you may have a more fundamental design issue with your schema if that's really what you want to do